# Simple function returns "Valueerror: setting an array element with a sequence"

Tags: arrays, numpy, sequence, valueerror

I would really appreciate if someone could enlighten me here... I have this very basic function which is set to return different values conditional on time in a model state - however the model crashes with the error:
"ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence" and the arrow pointing at the piece of code b3 = ... Any ideas? (Btw, the time_in_b3 is just a list that gets appended with each model step if the agent is in that state).

```
def from_b3(age, time_in_b3):
"""

If returning 1: agent survives untill next cycle
Else: agent transfers to state f1 (bc specific mortality)
If agent stays for a period of t = 10 cycles, transfers to state_a1
"""

true_pr_b3 = [(1 - tp_b3(age)),
              tp_b3(age),
              0
              ]
if time_in_b3==10:
    true_pr_b3 = [0, 0, 1]

b3 = np.random.multinomial(1, pvals= true_pr_b3)
return b3
```

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: What is tp_b3? also, could you provide a particular input on which the function crashes?

Comment: tp_b3 is a function that returns a transition probability from state b3 to death dependent on the model agents age.

Comment: And on what kind of input it crashes? For example if def tp_b3(x):
    return 2*x then from_b3(0.2, 5) returns array([0, 1, 0]), so it does work for some inputs

Comment: This is the last part of the error
    166                 if self.state_b3 == 1:
--> 167                     if from_b3(self.age, self.time_in_b3)[1] == 1:
    168                         self.state_f1 += 1
    169                         self.state_b3 -= 1
M:\pc\\share\Transitions.py in from_b3(age, time_in_b3)
    193         true_pr_b3 = [0, 0, 1]
    194 # Event for agent each step | transition probabilities, own age
--> 195     b3 = np.random.multinomial(1, pvals= true_pr_b3)
    196     return b3
mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.multinomial (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:32957)

Comment: sorry for the messy look, couldn't paste it all in properly... The code I pasted above actually works as far as I can see, but it might be the if-statement for the time_in_b3 variable causing problems

Comment: Did you check that that tp_b3(age) returns a number between 0 to 1? As far as I can see, if this holds, the code should work.

Comment: Ok, I think you're right. tp_b3 returns :
   31    0.080701
   Name: p_die_stIII, dtype: float64

Should I make a new variable with just a list of probabilities for example in stead?

Comment: This should work (as long as all probabilities are between 0 to 1 and their sum is 1).

Comment: Yes, it does. I think I know now, seems to be a problem with the  if time_in_b3==10, I think this must be set to  if time_in_b3>=10 instead. I'll try it and see what happens. Thanks for your insights!

Comment: Add traceback info to the original post with edit; it does not format well in comments.  Same for major code additions.  You also need to show the `time_in_b3` value in the problem case.  The `[0, 0, 1]` values works fine.  But about other times?  The error suggests it looks something like `[[0,1,2],0,1]`.  One or more values in the list are lists or arrays.